# Flutter filtering list in list in list

Tags: flutter, dart, filtering

I have three models: Order, Product and `IndividualProduct`
The model Order contains a list of Products `List<SingleOrderProduct>? orderProductList`.
A Product contains a list of `IndividualProducts` `List<SingleOrderIndProduct>? orderIndProductList`.

I have a list of `deliveredOrders` (List deliveredOrders) and I want to filter based on a field of IndividualProduct (the field is called "category") and get a list of Orders back that contains the category in an IndividualProduct.

I am able to filter in based on fields of the `IndividualProducts`:

```
      List<SingleOrder> searchedOrdersName = _orderStore
          .deliveredOrders
          .where((order) => order.orderProductList!
              .where((s) => s.name!.toLowerCase().contains(searchLower))
              .toList()
              .isNotEmpty)
          .toList();
```

But I am not able to use this method to filter in the more nested orderIndProductList. I have this too but of course it doesn't work:

```
List<SingleOrder> searchedOrdersCategory = [];
for (SingleOrder order
          in _orderStore.deliveredOrders) {
        List<SingleOrder> orderTemp = [];

        for (int i = 0; i < order.orderProductList!.length; i++) {
          for (int j = 0;
              j < order.orderProductList![i].orderIndProductList!.length;
              j++) {
            if (order.orderProductList![i].orderIndProductList![j].category!
                .contains(searchLower)) {
              orderTemp.add(order);
            }
          }
        }
        searchedOrdersCategory = orderTemp;
      }
      searchedOrdersCategory.toSet().toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do the reverse, remove all registers that not contains in you match.

```
for (var order in lstOrder) {
  for (var product in order.lstProduct) {
    product.lstIndividualProduct.removeWhere((IndividualProduct ip) => !ip.category.toLowerCase().contains(categorySearch.toLowerCase()));
  }
  order.lstProduct.removeWhere((Product product) => product.lstIndividualProduct.isEmpty);
}
lst.removeWhere((Order order) => order.lstProduct.isEmpty);
```

remember to put a negative **!** in your category condition

```
product.lstIndividualProduct.removeWhere((IndividualProduct ip) => !ip.category.toLowerCase().contains(categorySearch.toLowerCase()));
```

let me know if is this that you need.

Comment: Hi Fabio, I put some extra brackets like this !(ip.category!.toLowerCase().contains(searchLower.toLowerCase())) and then it worked like charm. Thanks a lot for your help!